# Borrower, platform, SPV relationship with borrower payment dependent notes?

Tags: debt, real-estate, structured-finance

As you know, real estate crowd funding platforms are taking off at the moment. Platforms connect investors to real estate assets. I am having an issue with understanding how exactly borrower payment dependent notes work. I simply want more details about the SPVs involved. Is the underlying loan simply a loan and not a debt security? Does the platform directly lend the money or do they do it through a different SPV? And then the platform creates a different SPV to which it issues these borrower payment dependent notes? Would the investors then be buying a pro rata share of the SPV? Thank you so much.

Comment: perhaps it would be platform / geography specific? i.e. Funding Circle has https://www.fundingcircle.com/home/terms-and-conditions and subsection "Loan Conditions"